# Adding warehouse selector to the custom field in acumatica

Tags: selector, lookup, acumatica

I created a custom field and trying to add the warehouse selector to it.I try to read from the customization guide and tried it but,the selector does not show up in the custom field.
This is the code I tried.
**#region UsrCustomSite
[PXDBInt]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Warehouse", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<IN.INSite.siteCD>),typeof(IN.INSite.descr),DescriptionField =(typeof(IN.INSite.siteCD)),SubstituteKey =(typeof(IN.INSite.siteCD)),DirtyRead =true)]
public virtual int? UsrCustomSite { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustomSite : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field { }
#endregion**
Am I missing something here?

Comment: The code looks fine and any misconfiguration on the DAC would result in an error message but the selector should still be rendered in the UI. 

Your issue is likely with the ASPX page, assuming you added the control via the Customization Project Editor I would recommend deleting the control and adding it again, make sure to select the Selector control and not the NumberEdit control.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.I tried adding it again but the selector is still not visible.And,my custom field is already a selector control.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<IN.INSite.siteCD>)
```

to

`[PXSelector(typeof(Search<IN.INSite.siteID>`)

You are storing an int so you want the id, the substitute Key setting will make it so that the UI will show the CD.